# Use and, or conditions while using Case,When

Tags: django

Anyone know in the following query how can I use AND condition?

```
q = Food.objects.all().annotate(open=Case(When(days__day=today,then='blahblah'),When(start_time__lte=now and end_time__gte=now,then='blabla')))
```

On the second `when` I want to check if the now value is between start and end time but it seems like the 'and' keyword is not working there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) objects so:

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, When

q = Food.objects.annotate(open=Case(
    When(days__day=today, then='blahblah'),
    When(Q(start_time__lte=now) & Q(end_time__gte=now), then='blabla'),
)
```

Use `&` to AND two Q objects and `|` to OR them.